# scraping nested xml using cheerio

Tags: xml, node.js, scrape, cheerio, pubmed

I'm trying to scrap some PubMed data using cheerio. The following script works ok but when some xml tag does not exist, it generates an erroneously ordered output.

```
var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio');
request('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&id=23545583,23103438', 
  function(error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    for (var i = 0; i < $('PubmedArticle').length; i++) {
        console.log($('PubmedArticle PMID').slice(0).eq(i).text());
        console.log($('PubmedArticle DateCreated Year').slice(0).eq(i).text());
        console.log($('PubmedArticle ArticleTitle').slice(0).eq(i).text());
        console.log($('PubmedArticle Abstract AbstractText').slice(0).eq(i).text());
      };
});
```

In this example the abstract outputs below the first title instead second because first article does not contain abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I think I could overcome this using a different strategy:

```
var $ = require('cheerio')
var request = require('request')

function gotXML(err, resp, xml) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  var parsedXML = $.load(xml)
  parsedXML('PubmedArticle').map(function(i, article) {
    console.log($(article).find('pmid')[0].children[0].data);
    console.log($(article).find('articletitle')[0].children[0].data);
    console.log($(article).find('datecreated year')[0].children[0].data);
    if ($(article).find('abstracttext').length>0) {
      console.log($(article).find('abstracttext')[0].children[0].data);
    };
  }
  );
}

var domain = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&id=23545583,23103438';
request(domain, gotXML);
```